Test Function Generation with specific properties.
Construct a test function  $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$  with the following properties $ 0 \leq \varphi(x) \leq 1 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $, $ \varphi(x) \equiv 1 $ for $ |x| < 1 $, $ \varphi(x) \equiv 0 $ for $ |x| > 2 $.
The general bump function is defined as  $\varphi(x) :=\begin{cases}
        \exp{\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}}, & |x|<1,\\
        0, & |x| \ge 1.
    \end{cases}$
The idea is to scale it so that this converts to a test function that follows the properties above, but I have no clue how to start the process. Does anyone know any way to construct test functions with certain properties?

I find it easier to start with
$$
f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, \ x\mapsto \begin{cases}\exp\left(-\frac 1x\right), & x>0 \\ 0, & x\leq 0\end{cases}.
$$
$f$ yields a smooth transition to a constant value. If we define
$$
g(x):=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)},
$$
we get a function that smoothly transitions between $0$ for $x<0$ and $1$ for $x>1$. You can use
$$
h(x):=g(2+x)g(2-x)
$$
if you want $h\equiv 1$ for $|x|<1$ and $h\equiv 0$ for $|x|>2$.
It might be instructive to look at this step by step, e.g. with https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4uefdobyhl

Where did you get that $f$? Is is coming from the bump function $\varphi(x)$?

No, it's just a very common example for a smooth function that is not analytic.

I tried using the same transformations that you used, but it's a dead end.

That's why I said that I find it easier to start with the function $f$ from my post, because relatively simple transformations yield the desired result.
